# Organic chemistry Reaction mechanism

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Which one is more stable, alkyl carbocations or aryl carbocations and why?

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the matter. Homework question should show some efforts from you before we help you, so that we can see where you have problems and guide you along the way. Especially as this question is a quite basic one which gets addressed in every introductory organic chemistry textbook.

Answer (score 4):

If you want it nice and stable, you want charge delocalization, like in allylic and benzylic cations. Note that more aryl residues mean more delocalization, additional *+M* substituents provide further stabilization.

[image: triarylmethane dyes]

Take the cations of *malachite green* (**1**) and *crystal violet* (**2**) as an example and **draw some resonance structures**.

Compare these with an alkyl cation or an aryl cation.

Answer (score 1):

Steric hindrance might kinetically stabilize a tris-alkyl carbenium ion, such as (*tert*-Bu)$\ce{_3C^+}$.  Delocalized aromatic systems leave it in the dust - **tropylium**.